# Assignment tax calculator

Tags: java

I have a assignment to write a tax calculator, I have completed it but basically copied from my textbook.  I am just wanting a hint on how to re-write this... any help is appreciated as I am doing this online and this is my first class and I am finding it difficult.

I have attempted to put the calculation into a table but didn't really understand how to get it working...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxCalculater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Enter Filing status
    System.out.println( "0 = Single\n1 = Married Filing Jointly or Qualified Widow(er)\n" +
                    "2 = Married Filing Separately\n3 = Head of Household" );
    int status = input.nextInt();
    // Enter Income
    System.out.print("Please enter the taxable income: ");
    double income = input.nextDouble();

    //Compute taxable
    double tax = 0;

    if (status == 0){
        if (income <= 8350)
            tax = income * 0.10;
        else if (income <= 33950)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15;
        else if (income <= 82250)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (income - 33950) * 0.25;
        else if (income <= 171550)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (income - 82250) * 0.28;
        else if (income <= 372950)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
                (income - 171550) * 0.33;
        else
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
                (372950 - 171550) * 0.33 + (income - 372950) * 0.35;
    }
        else if (status == 1){
        if (income <= 16700)
            tax = income * 0.10;
        else if (income <= 67900)
            tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (67900 - 16700) * 0.15;
        else if (income <= 137050)
            tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (67900 - 16700) * 0.15 +
                (income - 67900) * 0.25;
        else if (income <= 208850)
            tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (67900 - 16700) * 0.15 +
                (137050 - 67900) * 0.25 + (income - 137050) * 0.28;
        else if (income <= 372950)
            tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (67900 - 16700) * 0.15 +
                (137050 - 67900) * 0.25 + (208850 - 137050) * 0.28 +
                (income - 208850) * 0.33;
        else
            tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (67900 - 16700) * 0.15 +
                (137050 - 67900) * 0.25 + (208850 - 137050) * 0.28 +
                (372950 - 208850) * 0.33 + (income - 372950) * 0.35;
    }
        else if (status == 2){
        if (income <= 8350)
            tax = income * 0.10;
        else if (income <= 33950)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15;
        else if (income <= 68525)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (income - 33950) * 0.25;
        else if (income <= 104425)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (68525 - 33950) * 0.25 + (income - 68525) * 0.28;
        else if (income <= 186475)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (68525 - 33950) * 0.25 + (104425 - 68525) * 0.28 +
                (income - 104425) * 0.33;
        else
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                (68525 - 33950) * 0.25 + (104425 - 68525) * 0.28 +
                (186475 - 104425) * 0.33 + (income - 186475) * 0.35;
    }
        else if (status == 3){
        if (income <= 11950)
            tax = income * 0.10;
        else if (income <= 45500)
            tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15;
        else if (income <= 117450)
            tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                (income - 45500) * 0.25;
        else if (income <= 190200)
            tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                (117450 - 45500) * 0.25 + (income - 117450) * 0.28;
        else if (income <= 372950)
            tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                (117450 - 45500) * 0.25 + (190200 - 117450) * 0.28 +
                (income - 190200) * 0.33;
        else
            tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                (117450 - 45500) * 0.25 + (190200 - 117450) * 0.28 +
                (372950 - 190200) * 0.33 + (income - 372950) * 0.35;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error: invalid status");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Display result
    System.out.println("Tax is " + (int)(tax * 100) / 100.0);
  }
}
```

The code above is working, just wanting some ideas/hints on how to write this in a different way. Thanks!!

Comment: try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I highly doubt that your code above is working correctly. Example: `if (income <= 33950)
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15;` This says that any income between 8350 and 33950 pays the exact same amount of tax if 4675, no matter if you earn 8351 or 33950. Much more likely that it should be `tax = 835 + (income - 8350) * 0.15;`

Comment: Thank you!  Still got it wrong even copying from a text book. Have fixed it up now. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't want a lot of stuff in your main method, you want it as clean as possible. With that in mind, see if you can create some general methods for the different tax brackets, perhaps in another class, and then call them from inside main. Maybe you could also find a way to use switch cases instead of all those if's.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved all the calculations into a class and call it from my main :)

Also changed all the if's to switch statements!